# how to check/uncheck checkbox by using value in query

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML CODE:

```
<form id="myform">
 <input type='checkbox' name='foo[]' value='1'>
 <input type='checkbox' name='foo[]' checked='true' value='2' >
 <input type='checkbox' name='foo[]' value='3' >
 <input type='checkbox' name='foo[]' checked='true' value='4' >
</form>
```

JS CODE:

```
$('input[name=foo]:checked').each(function(i,el){
    if(clusterVal == 'ALL')
        {
            /* what do I have to do here? */
        }
    array.push($(el).val());
});
```

how to check/uncheck checkbox by using value in query

Comment: Did you google it ?! https://www.google.com.lb/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=check+uncheck+box+jquery+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**As of jQuery 1.6,** the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

try this ..but this to just demo how to do check and uncheck

## DEMO

```
 $(function(){
        var el=$('input:checkbox[name="foo[]:checked"]');

        el.each(function()
          {
                         $(this).prop('checked', true);
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the **checked** attribute of the checkbox element to **true** or **false**, i.e.

```
el.checked = false;
```

If you want to do it with jquery, use the **attr** function an the **checked** attibute as well

Comment: Better to use `prop()` than `attr()` for `checked`. Even [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) say so.

Comment: @TimDown thanks for the info, haven't used jquery beyond some very small apps yet

Answer (score 1):

Hans is right, <strike>although `el` will likely be a jQuery object (`.each` method returns jQuery objects in this case. as Anthony pointed out, This isn't always the case.)</strike>But as Anthony pointed out to me, `el` won't always be a pure dom object. It can sometimes be a jQuery object, so the `checked` property isn't necessarily available. A couple of ways to deal with those cases:

```
$(el).get(0).checked = false;
$(el).removeAttr('checked');//or $(el).attr('checked',false);

$(el).get(0).checked = true;
$(el).attr('checked','checked');
```

Credit to Anthony for pointing out my thick-headedness on `$.each` and `.each`'s behaviour :)

Comment: There's a distinction between [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) in jQuery, but neither of them pass a jQuery object to the function **unless** you're using `$.each()` to iterate over an array of jQuery objects.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: which is the case, a jQuery selector returns an array of jQuery objects, but you're right, there is a difference between `$.each` and `.each`, I'll edit my answer

Comment: No, a jQuery selector returns a single array-like jQuery object containing actual elements.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Christ, you're right! I've always gotten into the habit of just using `$(this)` on `.each` loops, but of course, `this` wouldn't be a jQ object! thanks, and well spotted

Answer (score 0):

Use the prop or the attr to do this.
Something like this

```
$(el).attr("checked", "checked");
```

or

```
$(el).prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery API Prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

You can check or uncheck element following

```
$(element).prop('checked',true); // check
$(element).prop('checked',false); // uncheck
```